# Rails not correctly converting to UTC timezone when doing date compare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

All,

I have a query that is looking for conversations since a certain date to allow the mobile app to see if there are any updated conversations since the last time it checked.  What I am finding is that rails is not converting my "since_date" to UTC before making the query and I am getting incorrect results. (This is coming right from my functional tests)

The generated query is

```
SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "conversation_joins" ON "conversations"."id" = "conversation_joins"."conversation_id" WHERE "conversation_joins"."user_id" = 980190962 AND (last_message_at > '2014-10-05 11:46:22 -0500')
```

The result is

```
[#<Conversation id: 980190962, last_message_id: 298486374, user_ids: nil, last_message_at: "2014-10-05 15:48:22", message_count: 2, created_at: "2014-10-05 16:48:22", updated_at: "2014-10-05 16:48:22", key: "298486374,980190962">]
```

Notice the returned conversation has a UTC last_message_at date/time of "2014-10-05 15:48:22" and the query is looking for "2014-10-05 11:46:22 -0500" which is "2014-10-05 16:46:22" meaning it should not be returned.  To confirm this, I did the same thing looking X hours ahead and the conversation was NOT returned once I hit 6 hours ahead which is matching my time zone speculation.

Do I need to explicitly change the Date/Time to UTC in my controller before creating my query or should rails be doing this for me since the time zone is included already?  My Rails version is "3.2.13"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that queries has to turn the dates to UTC before sending them to the `where` call. ActiveRecord does not transform query parameters.

Comment: Thank you Mauricio.  That is exactly what I was speculating.